# WSL ubuntu files recovery

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wsl2

I have WSL with Ubuntu distribution installed on Windows 10 machine. Today Domain account is changed and I restarted my machine and logged in. Since then I do not see ubuntu in the terminal preview profiles. How to launch or restore Ubuntu distribution or atleast how to recover files from the Ubuntu distribution?

Best Regards

Comment: You might find the files in the prior USERS profile (before you changed the domain account). ...  C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState  ....   See  https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux-an

Answer (score 1):

*Note:  It's important to not immediately reinstall Ubuntu if facing this situation, as it is possible for the old files/data to be overwritten when doing so.*

There are several things that might have happened when the account name was changed:

- First, did most of your other settings migrate?  In this case, the user profile data was likely copied from the old user to the new user (including, hopefully, WSL), but the WSL registry keys either don't exist in the new account or are still pointing to the old location. Assuming you haven't made the mistake of attempting to reinstall Ubuntu, your WSL2 files may still be intact.

  Using File Explorer check in your new user's `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\` for a directory starting with `CanonicalGroupLimited...Ubuntu...`.  If it exists, look inside it for a `LocalState` directory.  In that directory you should either have a `ext4.vhdx` (WSL2) or the rootfs of a WSL1 installation.  If it's WSL2, copy the `ext4.vhdx` file off to a safe location.  Then proceed below to *"Restoring"*.
- Second, as @John mentions in the comments, the data could still be under the old user profile.  Do you still have access to it, or did the IT team make a backup of some sort before migrating?  Look inside it for the same directory structure (`...\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited...Ubuntu...`) and use the same process as above to copy off the WSL2 `ext4.vhdx`.  Then proceed to *"Restoring"*
- Worst case, there's always the possibility that `%userprofile%\AppData\Local` was not migrated.  If there's no backup of it from the preview user profile, then the data may truly be gone.

###### Restoring

WSL1:  No great answer.  Just copy out any individual files that you want to recover.  You'll need to reinstall the WSL distribution, reinstall any packages in it, and just put the recovered files in your home directory, etc.

WSL2:  With the `ext4.vhdx` file in a safe location:

- Reinstall Ubuntu in WSL with the same username as before.  If the installation balks at the files already existing, then you may need to delete your existing `...\Packages\CanonicalGroup...` directory first.
- Exit Ubuntu
- `wsl --shutdown`
- Copy the `ext4.vhdx` file over the top of the newly created one in:

  ```
  %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited...Ubuntu...\LocalState\
  ```

Start up, and hopefully you'll find your previous installation intact.